# avoid reassigning variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following piece of code.

```
someFunction = async () => {
  let boolean = await this.someFetchFunction();

  if (!boolean) boolean = this.someOtherFunction();

  return boolean;
}
```

I was wondering what would be a cleaner/better solution to this code. Was thinking in a more ES6 way and to avoid reassigning variables

Comment: You could do this: `return await this.someFetchFunction() || await this.someOtherFunction();`.

Comment: FYI, I'm not sure this question meets the guidelines here because this is not your real, working code, but rather a made up example.  Conceptual coding questions probably belong in stackoverflow.  Questions about improving actual working code can be posted here.   See the Step 1: box on the right side of [this page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for posting guidelines.

Comment: @jfriend00 its a real example, just changed the variable names so that its not distracting or anything like that

Comment: Oftentimes attempts to simplify the code obscure actual relevant details and that's why both here and stackoverflow want you to post your actual, real code.  It's for your own benefit and people often simplify things out of the code they post that turn out to be relevant because they think they're only asking about issue A, but issue B is equally relevant and left out of the question.  And, real variable names are NOT distracting at all.  In fact, they should help people better understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this question does not match what this site is about. Please re-read the Help center page [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - specifically the third question. It would really help reviewers to know what the purpose of the code is. For more information, see [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/120114).